# Search for a general sub-string within a string in Java

Tags: java, string

I am new to Java. I want to ask how to search for a general sub-string within a given string.

For example:-
In the string **12345.67** I want to search for the sub-string **.67**
And in the string **1.00** I want to search for the string **.00**.

I basically want to search for the string after the radical **(.)**, provided the number of characters after radical are only **2**.

According to my knowledge search for general sub-string is not possible, I thereby asked for your help.

I wish to print the input (stored in the database) , a floating point number, into Indian Currency format, i.e, comma separated.
I even looked at various previous posts but none of them seemed to help me as almost everyone of them failed to produce the requite output for decimal point

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `String test = "12345.67"; test = test.substring();`  - Try learning about different substring methods and .contains() method. You will find yourself a solution for the problem.

Comment: *"According to my knowledge search for general sub-string is not possible"* what about a regex?

Comment: what about a simple `indexOf`

Comment: post your code which you worked on..

Comment: @ScaryWombat By far I have been looking at various in-built methods definitions to know if searching a general sub-string is possible

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt I tried this approach too but the problem is that there would be about 800-1000 entries and then perform an operation over them. So, I don't know the numbers after the radical point

The entry could be somewhat like #### . ##

Comment: @AlphaSniper you have answers below, think about accepting one, or comment the best one to explain what how requirement is not exactly answered

Answer (score 4):

*According to my knowledge search for general sub-string is not possible*

So you may learn a bit more, here [`String substring(int beginIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) method :

```
String str = "12345.67";
String res = str.substring(str.indexOf('.')); // .67
```

---

If you want to check that there is only 2 digits after `.` :

```
String str = "12345.67";
String res = str.substring(str.indexOf('.') + 1); // 67
if(res.length() == 2)
    System.out.println("Good, 2 digits");
else
    System.out.println("Holy sh** there isn't 2 digits);
```

Comment: @AlphaSniper or `lastIndexOf` in case you have more than one `.`

Answer (score 1):

You can use split plus the substring to achieve your objective

```
String test = "12345.67";
System.out.println(test.split("\\.")[1].substring(0,2));
```

In the split function, you can pass the regex with which you could give the separator and in a substring function with the number of characters you want to extract

Comment: Hi Sunder!

Thanks for the reply.
Being a novice myself could you please elaborate your code so it's easier for me to understand

Comment: the substring is not needed and will fail currently. -> `StringIndexOutOfBounds`

Comment: since in the question he mentioned that , he want the control over the number of charachters after the radical, substring will help in achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Next to the answer provided from @azro you may also use regex:

```
String string = "12345.67";
Pattern ppattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d{2})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
if(matcher.matches()){
   String sub = matcher.group(1);
   System.out.println(sub);
}
```

Which prints:

```
.67
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "12345.67";
String searchString = "." + str.split("\\.")[1];
if(str.contains(searchString)){
    System.out.println("The String contains the subString");
}
else{
    System.out.println("The String doesn't contains the subString");
}
```

Comment: `str.split("\\.")[1]` will throw if `str` doesn't contain a dot in it

Comment: @ThomasAyoub  The question was to "search for the string after the radical (.), provided the number of characters after radical are only 2.". That means the string will have a dot.

Comment: I didn't say you were wrong, I just warn about possible error :)